# Code for Iteratively Adding New Columns in SQL Server Table

Tags: python, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of columns to add into a SQL Server DB.

```
colList = ['title', 'docDate', 'coleadAgency',
           'usBusinessName', 'description',
           'acquCountry', 'ubo1Value', 'naicsCode',
           'mitigation']
```

I have a table called TAbby, and want to add these columns to it. I tried

```
for col in colList:
    cur.execute(""" ALTER TABLE TAbby ADD (?) NVARCHAR(255) """, col)
    cur.commit()
```

But I got error:

> ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '('. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: You can't parameterise DDL statements.

Comment: Thanks @DaleK does that mean I have no choice but to manually add all the columns?

Comment: No, it means if you want to do it that way you need to use string concatenation rather than parameters - I think anyway, I don't know python, but I am assuming that the ? uses a parameter behind the scenes. Try if you build your string yourself e.g. `"ALTER TABLE TAbby ADD " + col + " NVARCHAR(255)"`. The problem with this is its unsafe as you are open to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot parameterize identifiers like table or column names. Parameters are reserved for literal values. Therefore, dynamically string format the column name in SQL statement. (Square brackets around column name is to escape special characters, spaces, or reserved words).

```py
for col in colList: 
    cur.execute(f"ALTER TABLE TAbby ADD [{col}] NVARCHAR(255)") 
    cur.commit()
```

Actually, TSQL supports multiple, comma-separated columns in `ADD` clause. So, consider building with list comprehension:

```py
new_cols = ", ".join([f"[{col}] NVARCHAR(255)" for col in colList])

cur.execute(f"ALTER TABLE TAbby ADD [{new_cols}]") 
cur.commit()
```